# using PHP8.2 and SQLSrv/ODBC drivers

Tags: sql-server, odbc, github-codespaces

I have a PHP8.2 project that connects to a SQL Server backend. Runs fine in an Azure Web App

Playing with Codespace within GitHub at the moment as I'd like to be able to do quick smoke tests on changes when editing from my iPad and run the code there.

I've followed both the ODBC and PHP8.2 instructions:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver16

but still getting an error that sqlsrv_connect function is undefined (obviously the first SQL thing it hits)

Ideally, I'd love a pre-configured container that just has PHP8.2 and SqlSrv pre-configured that I can use in place of the default, or a set of idiot-proof instructions to upgrade the default container to support what I want.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76328889/edit) your question to include your `Dockerfile`. (I assume you're setting up dev containers to do this.) Possibly when following the sqlsrv instructions you missed changing an `8.1` to `8.2` somewhere.

Comment: I am using the default container that gets offered, no over-rides. been pretty careful to make sure all 8.1 to 8.2 replacements were made in scripts above, but can't find a sqlsrv.so installed anywhere